# Forward local SSH credentials to Docker container inside Vagrant VM

Tags: docker, vagrant

Does anyone know if this is possible, if so how can I do it?  I have ssh credentials on my computer that I need to use from within the docker container so I can access certain external services.

Comment: Did you try with the option `--volume ${HOME}/.ssh/:/home/docker-user/.ssh/:ro \`  that would mount your `.ssh` directory into the homedir of the docker user as read only?

Comment: @Auzias unfortuantely, i'm unable to do this as my container is built as a part of a huge deploy service

Comment: Why can't you? Without anymore details it seems tough to help you ;) Maybe you should detail the huge deployment.

Comment: @Auzias would `--volume ${HOME}/.ssh/:/home/docker-user/.ssh/:ro` be used as a flag for the `docker run` command?

Comment: @Auzias looks like i can't use that flag.

Comment: Maybe you should detail the __"can't"__ so we can provide you more help.